# With io_uring is it possible to do an atomic write and tell?

Tags: linux, io, system-calls

I would like to append to a file opened in O_APPEND and know where the data was written.  Writing and then making a tell call isn't useful as between the system calls there could be a context switch and something else writes to the end of the file.  So I would like something that does it as a single call.

I want this because I have have been experimenting with developing an append only database that makes use of the property that files opened in O_APPEND can be appended to atomically [1] to resolve synchronization issues.

I have been skimming through the documentation for io_uring and I am unsure but it looks like it may permit this to happen. Am I correct and if so how would that be done.

[1] Reading of the POSIX standard, man pages and emails from Linus all indicate that appending data smaller then 4KiB to the end of a file opened in O_APPEND mode will be atomic. NFS breaks this requirement however not working on NFS is a acceptable limitation.

Comment: Yes.  thanks I've corrected that.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35256561/2732969 also confirms that O_APPEND don't interleave relative to each other but that answer doesn't give any clues on how to found out what position the append happened at)